# Externally Modifying a File Breaks Writable Streams in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, stream

I've got a simple logging tool to write log data to disk, it works like this:

1. Use `fs.createWriteStream` to create a writable stream using the flags 'a' for appending. This creates or opens the file for me to write data to.
2. Use `writeStream.write()` to write data to my log file.

This works perfectly, except for in these two cases:

1. I open the log file while my application is running, change something, and save the log file.
2. I delete the log file while the application is running. Expected behavior is to recreate the file and keep logging away.

In both cases I can still call `writeStream.write()` with no error.

Inspecting my `writeStream` object after I either modify or delete the log file while the application is running shows the `writeStream.writable` property to be `true`. Each time I call `writeStream.write()` the `writelen` property increases which leads me to believe the `writeStream` thinks that everything is OK, even though it is not.

My questions:

1. Why does modifying and saving my log file externally cause `writeStream.write()` to stop writing data to my file? How do I fix it?
2. Why does deleting my log file externally cause `writeStream.write()` to stop writing data to my file? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Everything *is* OK, as far the write stream is concerned. When you delete the file you are in effect removing an entry in the directory, but the original inode is not deleted, and your app that has it open keeps writing to the disk, only you don't have a pointer to it (a dir entry), so can't see. You will notice that free disk space keeps decreasing, which tells you that things are indeed written. When the app closes the file it is *then* removed (since no references are left pointing to it), at which point the free disk space will increase again.

The standard practice for you are trying to do is to send a signal (`SIGHUP` or `SIGUSR1` to the app), and in the signal handler have the app close and re-open the file. This is called "log rotation". There are many node packages that do this for you, or you can do this yourself for the practice :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Can you point me in the right direction for instructions on how to send signals?

Comment: Depends on where you are sending the signal from. If the command line or a shell script then `kill -SIGHUP pid`. There are equivalent library functions in node, Python, Ruby, etc.